# Adicionar uma barra de progresso depois de um submit

Tags: php

Olá, tenho um script que faz upload de alguns arquivos, muitas vezes arquivos pesados. Quando executo o submit ele faz o upload, porém não mostra nada em tela até que o navegador copie até o servidor. Gostaria de adicionar uma barra de progresso, será que tem como? Caso sim, alguém tem exemplo. Agradeço segue meu código.

> HTML

```
<div class="row">
<form method="post" action="#ACTION_CADASTRO#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <fieldset>
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
           <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo">
        </div>
     </div>
  <hr>
<div class="button-group" id="botoes-form">
 <button class="success large button fi-check" type="submit"> Enviar Dados</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div>
```

> PHP

```
if (empty($_FILES['arquivo']['name'])) {  

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
    return "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' TYPE='text/javascript'>
            alert('Arquivo enviado com Sucesso.');
             window.location = 'home';
    </SCRIPT>";
    }
}
```

Comment: pesquise por “upload progress bar”

Comment: Recomendo usar JavaScript ou Jquery!

Comment: veja também com bootstrap. Eu amanhã faço uma resposta.

Comment: Pra adaptar no framework é tranquilo, o problema é o javascript...